# Coherence JMX ListenerKeyCount value?

Tags: oracle-coherence

the documentation says the ListenerKeyCount is `the number of key-based listeners currently registered with the StorageManager`.

that said, we are seeing values for this that are don't seem to add up...

- values > 0 when there aren't any application created cache listeners
- values significantly higher than the actual number of application created cache listeners

seems like this metric includes all references to the cache that needs to be synchronized across the cluster (L1 client caches, other L2 back caches, etc) rather than explicit application listeners...any thoughts?

Answer (score 1):

My guess is that you are using near caching, which often (behind the scenes) places listeners on the keys that it needs to listen to in order to maintain cache coherency. Does this match what you are doing?

Comment: yep, we are using near caches...that was our assumption as well that the internal listeners Coherence spun up were being counted as well...its a pretty worthless stat if that is the case...thanks for the input though